How to add range of floating numbers with select slider in streamlit
I have a sqlite database with longitude values in which range between 24.90000 to 24.99999. The code I'm trying is this:
longi_range = np.arange(24.90000, 25.00000)
long_range = st.select_slider("Select Longitude range.. ",24.90000,24.99999,(24.90000,24.99999))
st.write("longitude range: ",long_range[0],long_range[1])

and I am getting the error:
TypeError: Object is not an iterable and could not be converted to one. Object: 24.9


What's the problem? Does your code produce an error or does it just not behave as expected? What is expected? Please edit your question with more information

can you check now i have added the error i am encountering.

I think sliders have a default minimum step size of 0.01, as your values are less than that apart, streamlit can't iterate between them with that stepsize. I think there is a step parameter that you can add into your select slider like: step=0.00001, I haven;t tried it though, so I won't write an answer unless it works

np.linspace may be more appropriate than np.arange here
